# Playing m3u8 form local storage

Tags: android, media, m3u8

We want to play m3u8 with ts files stored locally on SD card in Android 4.0 and above devices.

I tried using video TAG inside HTML residing locally on the SD card and android native media player.

Both the codes are failing with the error. The same set of ts and m3u8 files are working fine when played from online when served from a webserver connected through http.

Can we play m3u8 using native support for files stored offline or do we need to use 3rd party libraries. I searched in internet and didn’t find article about not supporting the same.

Any help or recommendation would help my work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How about using something like https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg in your application, convert and then playing?

Comment: @Slartibartfast Thanks for response. I will try FFMpeg. Before we move into 3rdparty library just wanted to make sure that default Android implementation does not work with local filsystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue Solved**

we used nano http server to serve m3u8 file to with all videos parts. Very simple and easy way to play m3u8 video file.

Comment: May i know how to install nano http server in android ? i need to play m3u8 from sd card.

Comment: please look for " Nano Httpd'' git public repository. U have source code over there. Its just a single file that u need add and start off, works well with android sdk (no need external jars).

Comment: Thanks for reply. could you tell me how to add it to android. Is it an app or i need to write a program for it? is there any tutorial to get it running on android ?

Comment: no external app needed. Its just one file need to add in your source code. And u need to set the root directory for the server